# does anyone remember the options to CL.EXE from Visual C version 5?

Tags: c, cl.exe

...specifically, the /AL option? I am porting some ancient C (a Freescale nee Motorala M68000 simulator) and I can't find it on MSDN. Google retrieves many non-related links, and the Wayback Internet Archive chokes beyond the "Product Release" page. Note that this switch seems not to be present in version 6, but resurfaces in .Net as:
"/AL Specifies a directory to search to resolve file references passed to the #using directive"
These files are neither C++ nor C#, su that ain't right...

an example: cl -c -AL CODE1.C

Comment: I don't actually have MSVC 5, I am attempting to port to Linux. As it turns out, this flag is the least of my worries...

Answer (score 4):

I guess it sets the memory model to Large. That page reminded me of it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225257%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Oh, those were the days...

**Update:** Here's the full set: http://gunkies.org/wiki/Microsoft_C_5.1